# How simulate blockchain and smart contract in VANET?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, mining

I am a beginner in the blokchain, I am blocked how I start simulate a blockchain and smart contract in vanet.
Can you help me and inform me how I have to simulate blockchain and smart contract in the vanet. What tool do I use, what language of development, how do I build blockchain in the vanet?

Comment: What do you mean with VANET?

Comment: @Ismael VANET is Vehicular Adhoc NETwork

Comment: @ismael how i can present an RSU and vehicle in blockchain (for example using ethereum platform)

Comment: Sorry, but I've never worked with that type of networks.